# Highstock bug: navigator doesn't work when startOnTick/endOnTick set to true on datetime xAxis

Tags: highcharts

When startOnTick and/or endOnTick are set to true for a datetime xAxis, dragging the navigator left and right expands it until it fills up the whole range of data.

See:
http://jsfiddle.net/L3t4s/2/

Duplicate code below:

```
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 600px"></div>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/usdeur.js"></script>
$(function() {
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        chart: {
            plotBorderWidth: 1
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 4
        },

        xAxis: {
            startOnTick: true,
            endOnTick: true
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data: usdeur
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by real time redraws while dragging navigator. To prevent this set `liveRedraw: false`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/L3t4s/4/

Comment: Thanks for the tip -- that does appear to be a valid workaround.  There's also another somewhat intermittent problem (see http://jsfiddle.net/WaddW/).  When dragging the scrollbar or the left or right edge, it gets into a states where the min/max dates keep changing as long as the left mouse button is pressed.  It doesn't happen every time but it does happen consistently.  The workaround works here as well but I'd prefer to leave liveRedraw enabled.

Comment: The problem occurs with all browsers that I've tested including Chrome, but it's intermittent.  Actually, I'm going to report it as a separate problem because it turns out that liveRedraw doesn't really fix it and I have additional information about it.